# Search a single index in elastichq REST Editor

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am used to Marvel plugin for elastic search but recently I need to work with Elastichq.

The query

```
Get /bda/student/_search
{

  "query":
  {
      "match" :
      {
        "name" :"tayo"
      }

  }
}
```

is valid in marvel but I keep getting *"Unexpected 'G'"* on elastichq.
I want to search  *student document of bda* index as shown in the query above.
A note on the Json Editor page reads

> All commands are issued in '_all' scope; meaning that the request will affect >all of your nodes, indices, or mappings

Does it mean I can not query a single index if I have multiple indices?

Comment: Might be stupid, but have you tried `GET` instead of `Get` (All capital letters)

Comment: Thanks Evaldas. I tried  that but still getting the same error.